# Distinct ROUNDED results in MySQL

Tags: mysql, distinct, distance

I have a DB of latitude\longitude points.  I am trying to get DISTINCT rounded results sorted by distance.  My query is as follows:

```
SELECT
   DISTINCT ROUND(`lat`,2), ROUND(`lon`,2),
   ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(LAT_HERE) )
          * cos( radians( `lat` ) )
          * cos( radians( `lon` ) - radians(LONG_HERE) )
          + sin( radians(LAT_HERE) )
          * sin( radians( `lat` ) ) ) ) AS distance
FROM `user_data`
HAVING distance <= 99
ORDER BY distance
LIMIT 100
```

The distinct is running before the round.  For example (29.333,29.334), (29.331,29.332) will display twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try use `GROUP BY`

```
    SELECT  ROUND(`lat`,2), ROUND(`lon`,2),
                   ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(LAT_HERE) )
                   * cos( radians( `lat` ) )
                   * cos( radians( `lon` ) - radians(LONG_HERE) )
                   + sin( radians(LAT_HERE) )
                   * sin( radians( `lat` ) ) ) ) AS distance
                FROM `user_data`
                GROUP BY ROUND(`lat`,2) 
                HAVING distance <= 99
                ORDER BY distance
                LIMIT 100
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you're not correct. DISTINCT runs on previously evaluated results.
Run for example:

```
select distinct round(a,2), round(b,2) 
from ((select 29.333 as a,29.334 as b) union (select 29.331,29.332)) t3;
```

The result is:

```
+------------+------------+
| round(a,2) | round(b,2) |
+------------+------------+
|      29.33 |      29.33 |
+------------+------------+
```

Comment: I only want to display 29.33 once.  I do not want to display it twice.  That is my issue.  Sorry if I did not explain it.

Comment: @user2072710 In OP you select 3 columns: longitude, latitude and distance. What your purpose is? Is you don't need one of them - just remove it from your SELECT clause.